# Can't solve this issue UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2, tomcat9, java-ee-8

i've tried alot to fix this issue but couldn't. I find, if we use "abstractBinder" then this could be fix but once i've my Binder in place, i start having 404 error.

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl
```

Please help

My Resource:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.walmart.services.helpers.IUserService;
import com.walmart.services.helpers.ServicesTest;

@Path("/sayHello")
public class ControllerTest {

    @Inject
    private IUserService service;

    @Inject
    private ServicesTest service2;

    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String method(@PathParam("name") String msg) {
        return service.method() + " msg";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/v2/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String method2(@PathParam("name") String msg) {
        return service2.method() + " msg";
    }
}
```

My resource configuration file:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest/*")
public class ResourceConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    public ResourceConfiguration() {
        //register(new MyBinder());
        this.packages(true, "com.walmart.services.*");
    }

}
```

My Binder [ if in place ]

```
public class MyBinder extends AbstractBinder
{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        bind(new ServicesTest()).to(ServicesTest.class);
//      bind(UserServiceImpl.class).to(IUserService.class).in(RequestScoped.class);

    }

}
```

Services:

IUserService and its implementation

```
public interface IUserService {

    public String method();
}


public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    @Inject
    public UserServiceImpl() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @Override
    public String method() {
        return "Welcome ";
    }

}
```

Other

```
public class ServicesTest {

    public ServicesTest() {
        System.out.println("created ");
    }

    public String method() {
        return "Welcome";
    }
}
```

WEbXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>com.walmart.learning.javaee</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

Now, i can access my resource using 
http://localhost:8080/javaeeLearning/rest/sayHello/h

Which gives me below errors

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.walmart.configuration.ResourceConfiguration] in context with path [/javaeeLearning] threw exception [A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=IUserService,parent=ControllerTest,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,2007960340)
2. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ServicesTest,parent=ControllerTest,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,10615079)
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.walmart.services.rest.controller.ControllerTest errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.walmart.services.rest.controller.ControllerTest
] with root cause
```

And to resolve, i uncomment my Binder in Resource configuration 
then i start having 404.

Please help....

Other details;

Pom

```
<name>javaeeLearning</name>
    <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
            <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
            <jersey2.version>2.23</jersey2.version>
            <jersey2.gf.cdi.version>2.14</jersey2.gf.cdi.version>
        </properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey2.x Dependencies -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Jersey2.x Dependency injection -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish/jersey-gf-cdi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.gf.cdi.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
```

Comment: You need to binder. Direct your focus to why you're getting the 404. Are you getting a 404 for all endpoints? Have you come to absolute conclusion that adding the DI services causes the 404? Is everything running correctly if you completely remove all the DI services?

Answer (score 2):

Make your JAX-RS resource a CDI bean like this:

```
@Path("/sayHello")
@RequestScoped
public class ControllerTest {
```

Then you don't need the Binder and injection should work.

Comment: Are getting exactly the same exceptions as earlier? If you are not in full Java EE environment (Tomcat?) you may also need to do what @user3544624 suggests in his answer.

Comment: @PanuHaaramo in which server do you run the code you've posted?

Comment: If your bean discovery mode in beans.xml is annotated please annotate your restful resource endpoint with context scope bean. thanks @PanuHaaramo

Answer (score 2):

You could set bean discovery mode to all in `beans.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

or annatate `UserServiceImpl` with an scope annotation (like `@Dependent`)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this but i've this file. and still not working.

Comment: you didnt register binder in Resourceconfig?http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/dependency-injection-hk2-jersey-jax-rs/

Comment: pls add init params that http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/dependency-injection-hk2-jersey-jax-rs/ mentioned to them( sevlet's config).